# Error: Request failed with status code 401 : Unauthorized in React.js and using setState for Authorization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

**Note - The following error occurs only for the first time click of my application's "submit" button and only on the first load of page. If I click on "submit" button again, it works perfectly fine.**

For fetching data from an API I am using axios.all and in order to authorize the JQL queries I need username and password. An authorization string (this.setState{authString}) is set before calling axios.all and inside each of these get calls, I use my this.state.authString for authorization.

```
onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    let iNumber = event.target.iNumber.value;
    let pass = event.target.password.value;
    let query = CURRENT_SPRINT_INFO;
    if (!iNumber || !pass || !query) {
      alert("Enter Valid iNumber, password and sprint info");
      return;
    }
    this.loadData(iNumber, pass, query);
  }

  loadData = (iNumber, pass, query) => {

    notify.show("Loading...", "warning", 500);
    const authString = "Basic " + btoa(iNumber + ":" + pass);
    this.setState({
      authString: authString,
      loading: true
    });

    axios.all([this.getBacklogItemsData(query), this.getBugsData(query), this.getWaveItemsData(query)])
      .then(axios.spread((backlogItems, bugs, waveTasks) => {
        notify.show("data Loaded successfully", "success", 3000);
        const { adhocIssues, scrumBoardIssues } = this.getSeparateBIItems(backlogItems.data.issues);

        this.setState({
          adhocIssues: [...adhocIssues],
          scrumBoardIssues: [...scrumBoardIssues],
          bugs: [...bugs.data.issues],
          waveBoardTasks: [...waveTasks.data.issues],
          loading: false
        })
        // set session variables
        setUserDetails(iNumber, pass);

      }))
      .catch(error => {
        notify.show(`Error occurred while fetching data`, "error", 3000);
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        throw new error(error);
      })

  }
```

On first load of page and on click of my submit button, it throws Error: request failed with status code 401: Unauthorized -> and when I debug and check, the authString is empty i.e. authString = "" -> this happens on my first GET call itself (i.e. inside this.getBacklogItemsData(query))

Once I click on my submit button again, it works perfectly fine

Inspired from: https://codesandbox.io/s/rm4pyq9m0o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For fetching data from an API I am using axios.all and in order to authorize the JQL queries I need username and password. An authorization string (this.setState{authString}) is set before calling axios.all and inside each of these get calls, I use my this.state.authString for authorization.

In event handlers react flushes all the state changes only when you exit the event handler.

Here I set up an example 
https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-firefly-v59yk

So during the execution of the event handler when you access `this.state.authString` it gives you the initial value with which you entered
the event handler.

So one way to solve the issue would be to use the second argument of [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to make sure state has been updated and component has been rerendered, like this

```
this.setState({
      authString: authString,
      loading: true
    }, () => axios.all(...));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this.setState is async. So you can use callback with setState like this:

```
this.setState({
      authString: authString,
      loading: true
}, () => {
   axios.all(...) // Call axios here to make sure setState done
});
```

More information, check docs setState [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)